# Hibernate show actual alias

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Below is sql that shows in console after I enabled show_sql. May I know is it possible do display actual full-name alias rather than

> y0_, y1_, y2_

when debugging?

> ```
> select this_.activitycode as y0_, 
> this_.type12name as y1_, 
> this_.type12id as y2_,
> ```

1. I would like to find out values assign to bean when executing  query.list(); (e.g. y1_ to bean.variable1)
2. How to display query.setResultTransformer in verbose/debug/trace mode ? to find out how hibernate assign result to the transformer bean.